# Vairable Assignment

Tags: python, variables, linked-list, output, variable-assignment

In the following linked lists problem, a 'dummy' and 'cur' is assigned to the head. All operations are carried out using cur. But when dummy is returned these changes are reflected there.

The snippet is below

```
def mergeTwoLists1(self, l1, l2):
    dummy = cur = ListNode(0)
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            cur.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            cur.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = l1 or l2
    return dummy.next
```

How is it so?

Comment: Are they lists?

Comment: Both dummy and cur are references to ListNode(0) - so changes to one will affect the other. You will need to assign ListNode(0) to dummy and cur using two separate assignments, so that they refer to separate instances of ListNode.

Comment: @HolyMackerel. No, you really don't want to do that. The whole point of this is to retain a reference to the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

`dummy` and `cur` are references to the same object, `ListNode(0)`. Compare with [this example on Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20b%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%0Aa%5B0%5D%20%3D%2011%0Aprint%28a%29%0Aprint%28b%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Comment: Thanks mate. Got it now. Unless we assign using seperate arguments, changes happen to both of em.